# Installed via USB with a set amount of system space, want to add more

Tags: partitioning, usb

I installed Ubuntu via booting from a USB with the image file on it, and at the time I set it so that it only has 100GB of storage and limited resources, is there a way I can change this to allow it to use all of my system storage and it's full resources(RAM etc)?

Comment: Are you using a virtualization software ? which one ? How did you configured the VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by limiting resources? A Ubuntu installation should utilize all available RAM (unless you're on 32-bit on a 64-bit system).

When it comes to partitions, you deliberately made them smaller, correct?

You cannot change the size of partitions while in Ubuntu- you must use a live cd.

Boot into a live usb/cd, install GParted, and unmount the drive you wish to resize partitions on.
If you are using swap, make sure to right click the swap partition and select "swapoff".

Then you can resize partitions as you wish.

Warning: resizing and shrinking partitions can result in data loss (while minimal). Take care and caution when doing this!